# Showing predicted intervals from a time series forecast on a map in R (spatial modelling)

Tags: r

I have gone past the stage of making a time series forecast in R from which I obtained an ideal forecast model through exponential smoothing. However, I would like to replicate this using a spatial file (Shapefile or netCDF) rather than the CSV file I initially used to show the predicted spots on a map. Any idea on how to go about this using r?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I need to perform time series forecast using an 11-year period data (2010-2020) in R. The data is spatial i.e. each event (6798 different events) is tied to a particular x,y-coordinates. I already made a two-year prediction in R using the variable and incident dates (univariate). However, I need to replicate it on a map for visualization.